# Parsing XML from a stream, C# / SoapUI

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, soapui

I'm trying to get the value of "payload" from the following piece of XML that's sent with SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="localhost">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:HTTPWebService>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <loc:input>Test</loc:input>
         <payload>Data</payload>
      </loc:HTTPWebService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's the C# bit:

```
string xmlPayload = "";

XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();

using (Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
{
    receiveStream.Position = 0;

    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    { 
        xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
        xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("/payload/@value").Value;
    }
}
return xmlPayload;
```

The problem is that currently "xmlPayload" ends up with the value of null and the request fails. The XML is properly loaded but for some reason "XmlPayload" is empty and SoapUi responds with "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." How can I get parse the "Data" value from "payload" properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting value of `"value"` attribute that clearly not present in your XML. Also it is not at root of the DOM.

It looks like you want

```
  xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//payload").InnerText;
```

(Notice `"//"` which means "any node starting from root" and lack of `"@value"` which means - attribute with name `"value"`)

Answer (score 1):

Alexei had it - except use "InnerText" instead of "Value" to get your "Data":

```
xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//payload").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the node is null, you will need to check that before you assign the variable.

Try this:

```
xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("/payload/@value") != null ? xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("/payload/@value").Value : "value not available";
```

However, I believe a better way would be using InnerText

```
xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.GetElementByTagName("payload") != null ? xmlSoapRequest.GetElementByTagName("payload").InnerText : "value not available";
```

The format is like this:

```
var variable = condition ? A : B;
```

It's basically saying that if condition is `true`, variable equals A, otherwise variable equals B.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine and you should be able to incorporate it back in to your original program:

```
string xmlPayloadText = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:loc=""localhost"">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <loc:HTTPWebService>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <loc:input>Test</loc:input>
        <payload>Data</payload>
    </loc:HTTPWebService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

        XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
        xmlSoapRequest.LoadXml(xmlPayloadText);
        var xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//payload");
        Console.WriteLine(xmlPayload.InnerText);
```